# Unable to find a Veins v 5.0 beginner tutorial

Tags: veins, traffic-simulation

as VEINS 5.0 is a major rewrite for veins, is it possible to find a basic example or tutorial regardless of the one offered on veins website ?
for example : creating a tic toc example integrated with veins ?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy start into Veins 5, I'd recommend downloading "[Instant Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/)" and starting to play with the `veins_inet` subproject, which is already imported into the workspace as a separate project, ready to be run. The project consists of only a few files and its [`VeinsInetSampleApplication` module](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc) is only roughly 60 lines of code, so should be straightforward to understand.